# Timing Java Bubble Sort algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, timer

I have to sort a various number of arrays of various sizes and time each sort. My timer is giving me very short times in nanoseconds but mostly zeros. I have changed the point to start and end timer trying to fix the problem but have been unsuccessful. Can someone please show me what my timer problem is?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BubbleSort
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  int m;
  int n = 0;
  int num_i = 0;
  long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
  long running_time;
  int temp;
  System.out.print("Input array size: ");
  n = input.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Input number of arrays: ");
  num_i = input.nextInt();

  for(int j =  0; j < num_i; j++){


  }
  int array[] = new int [n];


  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {

      for( m = 0; m < array.length; m++){

      array[m] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
      }

     //int[] sorted = new int[n];
     for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {

        for (int j = 1; j < (array.length - k); j++) {


          //System.out.println("Start Time: " + startTime);
              startTime =System.nanoTime();

           if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
              temp = array[j - 1];
              array[j - 1] = array[j];
              array[j] = temp;

           }
           long endTime = System.nanoTime(); 
           running_time = endTime - startTime;
         // System.out.println("End Time: " + endTime);
          System.out.println(running_time);
        }


     }

  }

   }
}
```

Comment: Your code is faster than the timer can measure, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One  problem is the code is only testing the time it takes for the if and swap code, not the entire bubble sort. I made a simplified version that takes about a second to sort 30,000 numbers.

The frequency of the timer is not in nanoseconds on most systems, depending on the computer and the operating system. On my system, Intel 3770K 3.5 ghz, under Windows 7 64 bit mode, the timer runs at 3.410312 mhz, or about 293.2283 nano-seconds per "tick". Under Windows XP, the timer runs at about 3.5ghz, or about .2857 nano-seconds per "tick", but this is probably rare these days.

If the testing is resulting in zero elapsed times, test with larger arrays. You could repeat the test many times, but caching of the data from multiple runs will affect the results.

```
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int m;
        long startTime;
        long endTime; 
        long running_time;
        int temp;
        int n = 30000;     // set to value rather than input from user
        int array[] = new int [n];

        for( m = 0; m < array.length; m++){
            array[m] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        }

        // benchmark sort time
        startTime =System.nanoTime();
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (array.length - k); j++) {
                if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                    temp = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime(); 
        running_time = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(running_time);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried running at 10,000/10,000 and got the same result.

Comment: @user3403708 - I updated my answer. I'm assuming that you want to time how long the entire bubble sort takes, as opposed to timing the if / swap statements. Doing a single bubble sort from your code on 30,000 numbers takes about 1 second on my system. I didn't check to see if the bubble sort is actually sorting the data.